# Is there a way to query the devices connected to COM ports to determine if a specific device is connect in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I want to determine if a specific device is connected to a COM port.
I currently have the following code, which uses QueryDosDevice to determine MS-DOS device names

```
TCHAR lpTargetPath[5000];

for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) // checking ports from COM0 to COM255
{
    std::string str = "COM" + std::to_string(i);
    DWORD test = QueryDosDevice(str.c_str(), lpTargetPath, 5000);

    // Test the return value and error if any
    // If successful, test = # of characters stored in lpTargetPath
    // If not
    if (test != 0) //QueryDosDevice returns zero if it didn't find an object
    {
        std::cout << str << ": " << lpTargetPath << std::endl;
    }

    if (::GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        cout << "buffer error" << endl;
    }
}
```

However, this just returns general device names as follows:

```
COM3: \Device\Serial0
COM6: \Device\USBSER000
```

Is there some other method to determine more specific information about the device so I can verify if a particular device is connected? Would the best way just be to poll the COM ports in use for some sort of signature input that would identify the device, or can I actually access serial numbers or some unique identifier (note the display name is just "USB Serial Device(COM6)" so not much help there)

Comment: You want to verify the port itself or you want to verify what is plugged into it?

Comment: I want to verify what is plugged in. IIUC, the code I already have verifies the port is connected to something, no?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just verifies whether the port exists.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I don't understand COM ports (well obviously). When I disconnect the device on COM6, this code only outputs COM3. And if a plug a different device it, in maps to COM5, and I get COM3 and COM5 from this code.

But regardless, I am wondering if theres a method that I can use to poll the devices returned by this function for unique identifiers

Comment: A plain, old fashioned RS-232 COM port has no such protocol to even detect if something is connected to it. If you know about what is supposed to be there - you might or might not be able to test it. A USB device acting as a COM device is a different story.

Comment: Com ports are blisteringly stupid. They know nothing about whatever's been attached. But if the com ports are coming and going, what you're describing is USB providing a com port. You may get more useful information digging through the USB devices list, but odds are high that you'll just be told "I am a serial port!" You'll probably have to talk to the device attached to the serial port and see which protocol it responds to.

Comment: I see, good to know. Yes, it is USB providing a com port in this instance.

Comment: Your question nicely illustrates why COM ports aren't plug & play and should be avoided for communication with devices connected via USB. But assuming that you have no real choice, you can query the USB vendor and product ID (if that helps). Basically iterate the registry starting at `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB` and find the entry with the subkey `Device Parameters\PortName` = COM3 (or whatever your COM port is). The path then contains something like `VID_1A86&PID_7523`, which is VID and PID.

Comment: @Codo I've found resource to do this in C#, but is there an interface to do this in C++? VID and PID is exactly what I am trying to find

Comment: @qwerasdfzxcv a lot of things in C# are just wrappers for the Win32 API, and a lot of .NET's source code is available online, so you probably can see exactly what the C# interface is doing and just write equivalent C++ code.

Comment: There are the official Windows API functions, designed for C, usable in C++, but very prone to mistakes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-functions. And there are open-source C++ wrappers, e.g. https://github.com/GiovanniDicanio/WinReg (haven't used it).

Answer (score 2):

The operating system only knows about the COM port, not what's connected to it.

If you know much about COM ports, you know they are quite simple - at least, the part that everyone actually uses is simple. There is transmit, and receive, and that is it. The computer is able to blindly send data through one wire, and the device is able to blindly send data to the computer through a different wire, and we just hope and pray that it all works out.

There isn't even a way for the computer to automatically know how quickly to send data. If it gets it wrong then it sends or receives gibberish.

Other ports like VGA have extra wires which allow the computer to discover which kind of screen is plugged in. COM ports do not have this. USB has a kind of data message the computer can send to ask the device what it is. COM ports don't have this either.

For this reason, the program that's using the COM port has to already know what it's talking to - for example, the user might select it from a menu.

---

If your computer doesn't have a COM port you might buy an adapter that plugs into your USB port. Then you can plug the adapter's COM port into something that needs a COM port. Because the adapter plugs into a USB port, the computer is able to know about the adapter and the port on the adapter, but still not what the port is plugged into.

Some USB devices have these adapters built in. Sometimes they are real adapters - the device actually has a USB/COM adapter chip that talks to the COM part of the device. Other times they are virtual - the device is just *pretending* to be a USB/COM adapter chip talking to a COM device. If your device is one of these virtual adapters, you might be able to find some information about the device by querying the adapter/port, and it might show up as e.g. "Device You Are Looking For Virtual COM Port". If the device is using a real adapter chip, though, it will probably just say e.g. "USB COM Port Chip", since the chip doesn't know what device it's a part of, and you're still out of luck.